# Keras: Using `crossentropy` loss in `flow_from_directory`

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use `flow_from_directory` to train my model. The loss I am using is `binary_crossentropy` which requires calling the `to_categorical` function on the `Y_train` data. I do not know how to do that for `flow_from_directory`, and the program is throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vgg16-sim-conn-rmsprop-2-main.py", line 316, in <module>
    epochs=25
  File "/home/yx96/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 8
8, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yx96/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 187
6, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/yx96/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 161
4, in train_on_batch
    check_batch_axis=True)
  File "/home/yx96/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 129
9, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model target')
  File "/home/yx96/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 133
, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected predictions to have shape (None, 2) b
ut got array with shape (100, 1)
```

The data generator I am using is:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    data_format="channels_last"
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    './train',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=100,
    class_mode='binary'
)
```

And the `fit_generator` is:

```
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2500,
    epochs=25
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using `binary_crossentropy` for the loss, you did right to set `class_mode='binary'`.

Where you probably failed though, and this isn't showing in your post because you didn't show us the model, is at the last layer of your model.

You probably have a `Dense(2, activation='softmax')`. This is the "one-hot" or categorical crossentropy version. If you want to work binary, you only output one value which will be between 0 and 1. You do it like this :

```
Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
```

I hope this solves your problem :-)

Comment: So, if I wish to do `categorical` crossentropy, instead of binary, for, say 10 classes, then do I still use `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`, or `Dense(classes, activation = 'softmax')`?

Comment: then you use Dense(10, activation='softmax') ! when you work in categorical, every output neuron is one class, the softmax makes the output normalized so that the sum of every neurons will be 1, ideally you will get something like [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] but most likely : [0.1, 0.2, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.00, 0, 0.5], telling you which is the most probable class.